# What is the smartest way to put an overlay on this div?

Tags: html, css

Currently finishing up my website and the one issue I'm having is getting a transparent overlay on each of my carousel elements. I want a transparent gray overlay to go over the elements so the color scheme stays flush.

I've tried a number of settings on the actual div, but it seems there is nothing you can apply directly to an element to make an overlay. What would be the smartest way to have an overlay on each carousel element?

Current Screen - http://i988.photobucket.com/albums/af6/jtbitt/portfolio-screen_zpsas84np5e.png

HTML -

```
<section id="portfolio" ng-controller="portfolioController">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row portfolio-row">
      <div class="portfolio-left col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      </div>

      <div class="portfolio-right col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
          <div class="portfolio-title">
            <h1><strong>DONE SOME STUFF.</strong></h1>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-filters-container">
            <button class="portfolio-filters" ng-repeat="language in portfolio.languages" ng-click="portfolio.projectSort(language)">{{ language.name }}</button>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-carousel">
            <carousel interval="portfolio.carouselInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
              <slide ng-repeat="project in portfolio.projectsToShow">
                <div class="portfolio-projects">
                  <img ng-src="{{ project.image }}" />
                </div>
              </slide>
            </carousel>
          </div>

          <div class="portfolio-button">
            <button class="label label-success">CONTACT ME =></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

CSS -

```
#portfolio {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: gray;
  background-color: #101010;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

#portfolio .container-fluid, #portfolio .row {
  height: 100%;
}

.portfolio-left {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../../images/jay-photograph.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-right: 3px solid #101010;
}

.portfolio-right {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 16.5vh;
}

.portfolio-content {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.portfolio-title h1 {
  font-size: 3.1vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.3vh;
}

.portfolio-filters-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.portfolio-filters {
  width: auto;
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
}

.portfolio-projects {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.portfolio-projects img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.6);
}

.portfolio-button {
  padding-top: 1.3vh;
}

.portfolio-button button {
  font-size: 0.7vw;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #101010;
  color: gray;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .portfolio-left {
    height: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a filter? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(128,128,128, 0.3), 
      rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.3)
    ),url(path of images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your code with a filter applied. you can play with the colour and the opacity.

```css
#portfolio {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: gray;
  background-color: #101010;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
#portfolio .container-fluid,
#portfolio .row {
  height: 100%;
}
.portfolio-left {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../../images/jay-photograph.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-right: 3px solid #101010;
}
.portfolio-right {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 16.5vh;
}
.portfolio-content {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.portfolio-title h1 {
  font-size: 3.1vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.3vh;
}
.portfolio-filters-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.portfolio-filters {
  width: auto;
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
}
.portfolio-projects {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.portfolio-projects img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.6);
}
.portfolio-button {
  padding-top: 1.3vh;
}
.portfolio-button button {
  font-size: 0.7vw;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #101010;
  color: gray;
}
.filter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .portfolio-left {
    height: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolio" ng-controller="portfolioController">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row portfolio-row">
      <div class="filter">
        <div class="portfolio-left col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-right col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="portfolio-content">
            <div class="portfolio-title">
              <h1><strong>DONE SOME STUFF.</strong></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-filters-container">
              <button class="portfolio-filters" ng-repeat="language in portfolio.languages" ng-click="portfolio.projectSort(language)">{{ language.name }}</button>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-carousel">
              <carousel interval="portfolio.carouselInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
                <slide ng-repeat="project in portfolio.projectsToShow">
                  <div class="portfolio-projects">
                    <img ng-src="{{ project.image }}" />
                  </div>
                </slide>
              </carousel>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-button">
              <button class="label label-success">CONTACT ME =></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't require much code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pseudo element to cover the images:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yt52tsd0/)**

```
.portfolio-projects {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.portfolio-projects img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.6);
}
.portfolio-projects::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.6);
}
```

```css
#portfolio {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: gray;
  background-color: #101010;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
#portfolio .container-fluid,
#portfolio .row {
  height: 100%;
}
.portfolio-left {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../../images/jay-photograph.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-right: 3px solid #101010;
}
.portfolio-right {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 16.5vh;
}
.portfolio-content {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.portfolio-title h1 {
  font-size: 3.1vw;
  margin-bottom: 1.3vh;
}
.portfolio-filters-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.portfolio-filters {
  width: auto;
  color: gray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 0.7vw;
}
.portfolio-projects {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.portfolio-projects img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.6);
}
.portfolio-projects::before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.6);
}
.portfolio-button {
  padding-top: 1.3vh;
}
.portfolio-button button {
  font-size: 0.7vw;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: #101010;
  color: gray;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .portfolio-left {
    height: 50%;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolio" ng-controller="portfolioController">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row portfolio-row">
      <div class="portfolio-left col-xs-12 col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="portfolio-right col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="portfolio-content">
          <div class="portfolio-title">
            <h1><strong>DONE SOME STUFF.</strong></h1>

          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-filters-container">
            <button class="portfolio-filters" ng-repeat="language in portfolio.languages" ng-click="portfolio.projectSort(language)">{{ language.name }}</button>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-carousel">
            <carousel interval="portfolio.carouselInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
              <slide ng-repeat="project in portfolio.projectsToShow">
                <div class="portfolio-projects">
                  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQ2g.png" />
                </div>
              </slide>
            </carousel>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio-button">
            <button class="label label-success">CONTACT ME =></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```